# Authenticate between desktop client and a web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-applications, oauth, desktop-application

I'm building a small web application using ASP.NET MVC3, in which I'm using the default ASP.NET Membership API to create and authenticate users.

There's also a small desktop client which updates the web application. My question is what would be the best way to authenticate the desktop client. Considering that users would register using their username and password via the website, I don't really want to store any user credentials on the desktop.

I was thinking about implementing an OAuth provider in my web application, and associating the token with the authenticated username. That way I would authenticate my desktop client like most twitter clients do now.

So basically my question, should I do OAuth, or maybe there's another popular option?

Answer (score 1):

Why not expose a login action method that returns a token? This would avoid the added complexity of an oauth service. As long as your mvc app is decoupled and using services, your client can consume these same services.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more? I'm not a web guy, unfortunately :(

Comment: With asp.net mvc you can expose an action method with a signature like 'public string Authenticate(string username, string password)'. This can be consumed by the client. Once the client has this token, it can send the token in lieu of credentials along with any other requests for data.